# Python TypeError: must be real number, not str

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib and I meet a problem when I study by myself

I have 3 Numpy arrays and try to put in a bar chart.

**years_5:**  array([1975., 1980., 1985., 1990., 1995., 2000., 2005., 2010., 2015.])

**ct_5**: array([  6,  21,  27,  28,  67, 163, 198, 192, 192])

**ct_norm_5**: array([ 0.72488688,  2.53710407,  3.26199095,  3.38280543,  8.09457014,
       19.69276018, 23.92126697, 23.19638009, 23.19638009])

Here is part of my code:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(14,4),linewidth=5,edgecolor='0.5')
ax.bar(years_5,ct_norm_5,3,facecolor='.5',alpha='.3',label='Movie Per Year')
```

But I got an error: TypeError: must be real number, not str

Can anyone gives me an idea, what does this mean?

Comment: Can you give the complete error trace. Also, on which line do you get the error?

Comment: AS mentioned https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html, the alpha param needs to be a float not a string as you provide.

Comment: `alpha=.3` not `alpha='.3'`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the official document,

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html

you code need change to:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(14,4),linewidth=5,edgecolor='0.5')
ax.bar(years_5,ct_norm_5,3,facecolor='.5',alpha=0.3,label='Movie Per Year')
```